# Вывод индексов пустых значений из списков

Tags: python, список, вывод, индексы

Есть список:

```py
field = [['a', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'b', ' '], ['c', ' ', ' ']]
```

Как вытащить с него индексы пустых элементов?

Пример:

```py
free = (((0, 1), (0, 2)), ((1, 0),(1, 2)), ((2, 1), (2, 2))
```

Comment: Коротко - двумя вложенными циклами for. Еще нужно определиться, что такое "пустой" элемент, потому что `' '` - это не пустой элемент, это пробел.

Comment: Да, не правильно выразился, не пустой, а с пробелом, примерное представление у меня есть, но как организовать не могу понять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```
import numpy as np
field = [['a', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'b', ' '], ['c', ' ', ' ']]
idx = np.where(np.array(field) ==" ")
res = list(zip(idx[0], idx[1]))
```

res:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: вывод немного не такой как просил автор вопроса

Comment: Красивше через `*` распаковать `res = list(zip(*idx))`

Comment: @CrazyElf я вот как-то привык избегать распаковки при работе с nd.arrays

Answer (score 1):

можно так

```
field = [['a', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'b', ' '], ['c', ' ', ' ']]

a = []
for el in field:
    x = [(field.index(el),i) for i, _ in enumerate(el) if _.replace(' ','') == '']
    a.append(tuple(x))


print(tuple(a))
```

сработает даже если больше чем 1 пробел в строке.
если это не надо просто замени

```
if _.replace(' ','') == ''
```

на

```
if _ == ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

Простое решение через циклы

```
field = [['a', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'b', ' '], ['c', ' ', ' ']]
free = []
for line in field:
    temp = []
    for num, sumbol in enumerate(line):
        if sumbol == ' ':
            temp.append(num)
    free.append(tuple(temp))
print(tuple(free))  #  ((1, 2), (0, 2), (1, 2))
```

Чтобы результат получился в круглых скобках, в конце он преобразуется в tuple. Если это не нужно, можно все оставить в списках

Answer (score 1):

однострочник:

```
tuple(tuple((i,x) for x,y in enumerate(j) if y==' ') for i,j in enumerate(field))

>>> out
'''
(((0, 1), (0, 2)), ((1, 0), (1, 2)), ((2, 1), (2, 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто вкину, как вариант. Логика собирать в итогвый кортеж та же, но подход к поиску оформлен через строку и регулярное выражение. Понятно, что код не универсален и не быстр (регулярки не имеют отношение к быстродействию). Но для расширения методов и практик подойдет

```py
import re

field = [['a', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'b', ' '], ['c', ' ', ' ']]

result = []
for  item in field:
    result.append([m.start() for m in re.finditer(' ', ''.join(item))])

free = tuple((count, value)  for count, r in enumerate(result) for value in r)
```